# Dans le texte cité dans le corps de la question, qu’est-ce que le participe présent exprime?

Tags: sens, reformulation, participe-présent

Le participe présent exprime-t-il une circonstance concomitante ou une conséquence dans le texte suivant:

Joanie a évolué vers un nouveau lieu de travail, le Centre des Ruisseaux, plus proche de sa maison. Jusqu'à il y a peu (vendredi passé), elle travaillait au Centre St-Clotilde avec des adultes atteints de troubles autistiques et de déficiences intellectuelles mais elle a maintenant opté pour une clientèle de jeunes, **laissant** derrière elle les adultes aux prises avec des troubles divers.

N’hésitez pas à me donner des variantes plus claires et plus élégantes du texte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est une notion de conséquence qui se dégage de cet usage du participe présent (Il me semble toutefois que la circonstance concomitante ne s'applique qu'au gérondif.). Cela découle du contexte puisque on comprend que la personne en question est partie et qu'elle abandonne des patients dont elle ne s'occupera plus. Le participe présent est considéré comme une tournure élégante de la langue écrite ; personnellement, je ne vois pas de phrases plus claire ou plus élégante, seulement des phrases équivalentes. Il pourrait y avoir une question en ce qui concerne le verbe « évoluer » (changement progressif), mais le contexte dans ce qui précède justifie peut-être ce verbe. Pour ne dire pas plus que « a choisi un nouveau lieu de travail », forme dans laquelle on comprend que le lieu a une certaine importance (cadre, clientèle particulière, etc.), ce verbe ne convient pas. Autrement, il manque une idée, et il faudrait dire quelque chose comme « a évolué vers l'idée de trouver un nouveau lieu de travail », mais alors il est difficile d'introduire cette circonstance dans la phrase sans la rallonger.

Comment: « Il y a calque non pas à cause d’un appui bancal, mais parce que ces participes expriment la conséquence, le résultat de l’action énoncée dans la principale – alors que, contrairement à l’anglais, le participe présent en français n’exprime généralement pas la conséquence. » Jacques Desrosiers

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=93HYa44F8eTc.html

Comment: Qu’entendez-vous par « La circonstance concomitante ne s'applique qu'au gérondif. » ? Dans  l’une de vos réponses récentes, vois écriviez, à propos de l’utilisation d’un participe présent, ceci: « Le restaurateur assurait le succès de son travail, prenant tout son temps. (circonstance concomitante) ».

Comment: @Antivlad Il est apparent que les grammairiens ne sont pas d'accord ; dans la réponse à l'une de vos questions j'ai aussi eu l'occasion de mentionner la conséquence comme étant une des possibilités qu'offre le participe présent. https://www.memoireonline.com/04/08/1029/m_approche-exploratoire-relation-consequence-description-implementation33.html

Comment: @antivlad En ce qui concerne la concomitance, il faut comprendre que la base du concept est souvent la simultanéité. « Elle regarde la télévision en tricotant. » (temps, simultanéité) ; « Elle tricote en regardant la télévision. » (temps, simultanéité de circonstance concomitante).  Ceci étant dit, en ce qui concerne la réponse récente, j'ai peut-être été trompé par les références suivantes : https://ameliorer-ses-ecrits.univ-cotedazur.fr/wp-content/ressources/PHRASES.publi/auroraW/co/02_EmploiPP.html. (1/2)

Comment: @Antivlad Pour l'instant, je ne crois pas que la circonstance concomitante puisse être associée avec le participe présent. Je vais changer l'example, et considérer qu'il s'agit du temps (« comme il prenait tout … », simultanéité). (2/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142467/discussion-between-antivlad-and-lph).